# How to message staff?

Tags: support

I've been asked to message staff regarding being disassociated with a post, but now I'm here, I can't see a way of messaging staff directly through the account only via email. How do I contact staff through the account rather than email?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, but the first dupe was outdated and more confusing than helpful so I removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button towards the bottom of each page that can be used for that purpose.